# Traits for SortedListWithKey

Tags: python, traits, enthought

I am using a `SortedListWithKey` class from the new `sortedcontainers` module ([link](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlistwithkey.html)). Is there a way to adapt the List trait to specify that I want a `SortedListWithKey(Instance(SomeClass), key=some_key)`?

To be more specific, how can achieve something like:

```
from traits.api import HasTraits, Instance, SortedListWithKey # i know it cannot really be imported

class MyClass(HasTraits):
    sorted_list = SortedListWithKey(Instance(ElementClass))
```

Comment: What do you mean by a `SortedListWithKey(Instance(SomeClass), key=some_key)`?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. What I want is a way to use `SortedListWithKey(Instance(SomeClass))` instead of `List(Instance(SomeClass))`. The `key` part is the detail of `SortedListWithKey`, which is a function used to define how the list elements are to be comparared.

Comment: It probably depends upon what class `SomeClass` is in your case. It certainly needs to be an iterable, and then what you provide to the `key` argument would need to be a callable written to act as the point of comparison for the elements of the iterable, which itself could be a Trait, as in the simple example below:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at your question again, I think what you are looking to for is a way of accessing the `SortedListWithKey` object as if it were a list and using the `Traits` or `TraitsUI` machinery to be able to validate/view/modify it. The [`Property`](https://traits.readthedocs.io/en/latest/traits_user_manual/advanced.html#property-traits) trait should help here allowing you to view the `SortedListWithKey` as a `list`. I have modified my code example below to have another trait be a `Property(List(Str))` and view it with a simple TraitsUI:

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedListWithKey

from traits.api import Callable, HasTraits, List, Property, Str
from traitsui.api import Item, View


class MyClass(HasTraits):
    sorted_list_object = SortedListWithKey(key='key_func')

    sorted_list = Property(List(Str), depends_on='sorted_list_object')

    key_func = Callable

    def _get_sorted_list(self):
        return list(self.sorted_list_object)

    def default_key_func(self):
        def first_two_characters(element):
            return element[:2]
        return first_two_characters

    def default_traits_view(self):
        view = View(
            Item('sorted_list', style='readonly')
        )
        return view


if __name__ == '__main__':
    example = MyClass()
    example.sorted_list_object = SortedListWithKey(
        ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth']
    )
    example.configure_traits()
```